# css rotating trapeze and heart-rate line

Tags: css, css-animations

We want to animate our logo which is working so far but I dont know how to make those gears appearing like trapeze? Also how to adjust this heartbeat line so its similar to the real log?

[image]

I know how to make a trapeze as there are lot of ready code snippets in the internet, but I am struggling to integrate this here.

```css
.parent {
  position:relative;
transform: scale(0.4);
}

.gear {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.gear .center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.tooth {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 75px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 45px;
  height: 250px;
  background: black;
}

.tooth:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.tooth:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.tooth:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#heart {
  position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    z-index: 9999;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#heart:before,
#heart:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #1D74BA;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

#heart:after {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

svg.heart-rate {
     position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    color: white;
    fill: currentColor;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="heart">
    <svg class="heart-rate" ersion="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="150px" height="73px" viewBox="0 0 150 73" enable-background="new 0 0 150 73" xml:space="preserve">
    <polyline fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="0,45.486 38.514,45.486 44.595,33.324 50.676,45.486 57.771,45.486 62.838,55.622 71.959,9 80.067,63.729 84.122,45.486 97.297,45.486 103.379,40.419 110.473,45.486 150,45.486"
    />
  </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="gear">
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
  </div>
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: consider SVG since you are working with SVG

Comment: http://geargenerator.com/#200,200,100,6,1,0,0,4,1,8,2,4,27,-90,0,0,16,4,4,27,-60,1,1,12,1,12,20,-60,2,0,60,5,12,20,0,0,0,2,-563

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achieved the trapeze with CSS gradient. You can use 4 gradients at 4 corners with appropriate angles to make it look like a trapeze.

```css
.tooth {
    background: linear-gradient(70deg,  transparent 10px, #000 10px),
                linear-gradient(-70deg, transparent 10px, #000 10px),
                linear-gradient(250deg, transparent 10px, #000 10px),
                linear-gradient(110deg, transparent 10px, #000 10px);
    background-position: bottom left, bottom right, top right, top left;
    background-size: 55% 55%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**Full working snippet:**

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(0.4);
}

.gear {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.gear .center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.tooth {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 75px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 45px;
  height: 250px;
  background: linear-gradient(70deg, transparent 10px, #000 10px), linear-gradient(-70deg, transparent 10px, #000 10px), linear-gradient(250deg, transparent 10px, #000 10px), linear-gradient(110deg, transparent 10px, #000 10px);
  background-position: bottom left, bottom right, top right, top left;
  background-size: 55% 55%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.tooth:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.tooth:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.tooth:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#heart {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 9999;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#heart:before,
#heart:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #1D74BA;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

#heart:after {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

svg.heart-rate {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  color: white;
  fill: currentColor;
  left: 50%;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="heart">
    <svg class="heart-rate" ersion="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="150px" height="73px" viewBox="0 0 150 73" enable-background="new 0 0 150 73" xml:space="preserve">
    <polyline fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="0,45.486 38.514,45.486 44.595,33.324 50.676,45.486 57.771,45.486 62.838,55.622 71.959,9 80.067,63.729 84.122,45.486 97.297,45.486 103.379,40.419 110.473,45.486 150,45.486"
    />
  </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="gear">
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! How to get rid off the small white line within the trapezes? I will then accept your answer and give bounty to you. Thank you!

Comment: @KrystianManthey Increasing the background size from 50% to 55% eliminates the white line discontinuity.

Answer (score 2):

Couldnt find a good solution for the trapeze but created a nice animated svg polyline:

```css
.parent {
  position:relative;
transform: scale(0.4);
}

.gear {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.gear .center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.tooth {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 75px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 45px;
  height: 250px;
  background: black;
}

.tooth:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.tooth:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.tooth:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#heart {
  position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    z-index: 9999;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#heart:before,
#heart:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #1D74BA;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

#heart:after {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

svg.heart-rate {
     position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    color: white;
    fill: currentColor;
    left: 213%;
    top: 5%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0.85);
}
path {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  animation: dash 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -500;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="heart">
    <svg class="heart-rate" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="689px" height="359px" viewBox="0 0 689 359" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" ><rect id="svgEditorBackground" x="0" y="0" width="689" height="359" style="fill: none; stroke: none;"/><path style="stroke:white;fill:none;stroke-width:4px;" id="e1_polyline" d="M106.204 222.314 113.506 219.658 124.126 226.296 130.1 203.728 136.738 222.977 140.721 218.331 155.987 230.943 164.617 207.047 169.927 223.641 176.565 219.658 180.547 224.969 196.478 224.969"/></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="gear">
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```